# ADO - How to write two cnn.execute commands running in the same time?

Tags: sql, vba, ado, execute

I have this two working commands and I want them to work together, because now IdTask is pasted to, for example, row 1 and Date to row 2. I want them in the same row. I'm using ADO.

```
 cnn.Execute "INSERT INTO dane([IdTask]) SELECT (qqq.[IdTask]) FROM qqq_  
WHERE Line= '" & Me.ListBox1.List(lItem, 0) & "' And Task = '" & Me.ListBox1.List(lItem, 1) & "'"
    cnn.Execute "INSERT INTO dane ([Date]) VALUES (#" & MDate & "#)"
```

Comment: You cant make them run at the same time. It doesnt work like that. You will have to find another alternative.

Comment: You can always insert two fields at the same time with an Insert Statement. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208861(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for yours comments. I go a little around -  I just added to range "qqq" column where is current date (now I am looking how do a autoupdate of it)

```
cnn.Execute "INSERT INTO dane([IdTask],[Date]) SELECT [IdTask], [Teraz] FROM qqq_
 WHERE Line= '" & Me.ListBox1.List(lItem, 0) & "' And Task = '" &_
 Me.ListBox1.List(lItem, 1) & "'"
```